# Can a US company ask prospective American employees, contractors or partners about their country of birth?

Tags: contract-law, employment, discrimination, nationality

I decided recently to sign up as a seller on Amazon.com.
The first step of the registration process however, asks about the applicants "Country of Birth".

Is this legal?

That seems to completely irrelevant and an opening for discrimination. I think the country will be worse off if in the course of ordinary business, people were asked about their countries of birth. In America, we're all supposed to be American (though I can understand in certain very sensitive national security situations)

If anyone can comment on the legality of this, I would appreciate.
As a follow-up question, I would be curious to know if Amazon can in any way be sued for asking this and what the potential risk/reward of such a lawsuit would be?

[image: Amazon Seller Registration Form]

Comment: For example, Arnold Schwarzenegger's country of birth is Austria, which prevented him from trying to become US president. IMO opinion he would have been a much better choice due to having more brain, more brawns, better ethics, and being an adult.

Comment: Did you ask Amazon about this?  What did they say?

Comment: Yes, I did ask Amazon about it. They sent a canned response saying that it's to ensure a safe marketplace for all vendors and customers.

Comment: @gnasher729 Perhaps, though Terry Crews has more experience playing a President.

Comment: Studoku, Schwarzenegger has significantly more experience being a senator of California, _and_ the guy is seriously intelligent.

Comment: The laws are going to very different for an employee vs the other roles you mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

**TL;DR:** You are likely to have a case in California, Colorado, New Mexico, New York, and Oregon. Read [this report](https://lawyerscommittee.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Online-Public-Accommodations-Report.pdf) for details and, if you've got the balls, file a lawsuit.

First of all, let's make the scope clear: this matter concerns just bare *contractual* relationship as opposed to employment. Amazon sellers are no employees of Amazon. They are **clients**. That is, they sign up and receive a long-term service. I therefore answer this question rephrased as "**Can one refuse to accept a new client based on their country of birth?**"

The answer would have been a very straightforward "No" if it concerned a brick-and-mortar service like a physical shop or restaurant. These places are called "[public accommodations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_accommodations_in_the_United_States)" — where discrimination on the basis of national origin is prohibited at federal level.

Amazon is an online service. Are these "public accommodations" for the purposes of [Title II of the Civil Rights Act of 1964](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_Rights_Act_of_1964#Title_II%E2%80%94public_accommodations) or related state-level laws? As per [this report](https://lawyerscommittee.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Online-Public-Accommodations-Report.pdf), it varies from state to state. In California, Colorado, New Mexico, New York, and Oregon they are, which is the basis for your would-be lawsuit(s) in these states. You may have luck in some other states too, but definitely not in Florida or New Jersey.

Before proceeding with a lawsuit you would need to rule out any possibility that the absence of your country of birth in the select box is unintentional (i.e. not a bug or mere omission). For this you would need to obtain a letter/message directly from Amazon, similar to the one cited in Dave D's answer.

Last question is, in the event the select box included *all* countries, would the mere presence of it in the form still amount to discrimination (as opposed to mere collection of information)? In this case, to prove your case you would probably have to be refused and somehow prove that the refusal was caused by your country of birth. This is hard because, again, the service sign-up form is no [job interview](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/51510/is-employment-discrimination-crime-or-tort-or-what).

> I would be curious to know if Amazon can in any way be sued for asking this and what the potential risk/reward of such a lawsuit would be?

Anyone can sue anybody. Fill in the forms, pay the application fees and whoah — you are already suing! How far will your suit go and, particularly, whether it will kick back is a very fact-specific question depending on too many variables. If you are not confident that you can research it yourself, you need to talk to not just a lawyer, but *your* lawyer.

Comment: "Before proceeding with a lawsuit you would need to rule out any possibility that the absence of your country of birth in the select box is unintentional (i.e. not a bug or mere omission). For this you would need to obtain a letter/message directly from Amazon, similar to the one cited in Dave D's answer." Can you explain what you mean by this? Just to be clear, including your country of birth is a requirement

Comment: "whether it will kick back" what do you mean by "kick back"?

Comment: They are not clients since Amazon pays them rather than the reverse. They are more like vendors providing a service to Amazon.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz most of them pay Amazon, for Amazon's "fulfillment" services

Comment: @CodyBugstein That is not true. Amazon purchases products from vendors which Amazon sells to customers. Vendors do not pay for Amazon's services. Amazon pays vendors to pack and ship. You can see the agreement [here](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/01/legal/VEVendorTsCsEff06042018._CB474167981_.pdf).

Comment: There are different kinds of "sellers". This question is mainly in reference to "3rd party" and "FBA" sellers, which makes up a huge bulk of them https://codisto.com/supersellers/2017/11/14/a-guide-to-the-different-seller-types-on-amazon/

Comment: @CodyBugstein You would need to show the court that you have attempted to resolve the issue with Amazon prior to suing them i.e. contact them to get a written confirmation that they consciously do not accept sellers born in Russia etc., not just forgot to include it in the list of countries of birth in the sign up form.

Comment: How can you prove that? Isn't the fact that they're asking about enough to show that they consider it a basis for discrimination ? For example if a baker asks if I'm gay, and then refuses to bake me a cake. how do I prove the gayness is the reason?

Comment: @CodyBugstein It's a form in a web app, not human-to-human interaction. Whoever created that form could have simply copied the list of countries of birth from the list of countries of citizenship, unaware that some countries are missing in there. You need to rule this human error out before alleging that it was intentional.

Comment: @CodyBugstein When a lawsuit that you file "kicks you back" it means you end up with losses and regret filing it e.g. you lose the case and get ordered to pay costs to the other party.

Answer (score 3):

[The EEOC states](https://www.eeoc.gov/national-origin-discrimination) that national original discrimination in employment is illegal, which is supported by [28 CFR Part 44](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=deff17e33139bf42d46be99d641aafb6&mc=true&node=pt28.2.44&rgn=div5) (discriminate means "the act of intentionally treating an individual differently from other individuals because of national origin or citizenship status, regardless of the explanation for the differential treatment, and regardless of whether such treatment is because of animus or hostility"). See also [Title VII of the Civil Rights Act of 1964](https://www.eeoc.gov/statutes/title-vii-civil-rights-act-1964):

> It shall be an unlawful employment practice for an employer -
>
> (1) to fail or refuse to hire or to discharge any individual, or
> otherwise to discriminate against any individual with respect to his
> compensation, terms, conditions, or privileges of employment, because
> of such individual's race, color, religion, sex, or national origin;
> or
>
> (2) to limit, segregate, or classify his employees or applicants for
> employment in any way which would deprive or tend to deprive any
> individual of employment opportunities or otherwise adversely affect
> his status as an employee, because of such individual's race, color,
> religion, sex, or national origin.

codified at [42 USC 2000e–2](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/2000e-2).

[The internet widely advises](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&sxsrf=ALeKk02F6jozp9p9VlQfFHC0GQp86P0DUA%3A1605716460892&ei=7Em1X6LbNY3L0PEP-6aNkAY&q=illegal%20employment%20interview%20question%20national%20origin&oq=illegal%20employment%20interview%20question%20national%20origin&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCCEQoAEyBQghEKABOgQIABBHOgkIABDJAxAWEB46BggAEBYQHjoICCEQFhAdEB46BAghEAo6BwghEAoQoAFQttcCWK70AmCK9wJoAHACeACAAaMBiAHhDpIBBDMuMTSYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiigYv6v4ztAhWNJTQIHXtTA2IQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) that asking such questions is illegal. The EEOC has a more nuanced view of the matter as articulated [here](https://www.eeoc.gov/employers/small-business/what-shouldnt-i-ask-when-hiring): they say

> We recommend that you avoid asking applicants about personal
> characteristics that are protected by law, such as race, color,
> religion, sex, national origin or age. These types of questions may
> discourage some individuals from applying, may be viewed suspiciously
> by some applicants, and may be considered evidence of intent to
> discriminate by the EEOC. If you do not have this information when you
> decide who to hire, it may be easier for you to defend your business
> against a hiring discrimination complaint.

Before reaching a conclusion, we should check what an employee is ([42 USC § 2000e(f)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/definitions/uscode.php?width=840&height=800&iframe=true&def_id=42-USC-1193469614-1546477209&term_occur=999&term_src=title:42:chapter:21:subchapter:VI:section:2000e%E2%80%932)), namely:

> an individual employed by an employer, except that the term “employee”
> shall not include any person elected to public office in any State or
> political subdivision of any State by the qualified voters thereof, or
> any person chosen by such officer to be on such officer’s personal
> staff, or an appointee on the policy making level or an immediate
> adviser with respect to the exercise of the constitutional or legal
> powers of the office. The exemption set forth in the preceding
> sentence shall not include employees subject to the civil service laws
> of a State government, governmental agency or political subdivision.
> With respect to employment in a foreign country, such term includes an
> individual who is a citizen of the United States.

This just tells us that in writing the law, Congress left it somewhat open what an "employee" is.

An Amazon seller is, on the face of it, not an employee of Amazon, instead, a seller is an independent contractor. Of course that is a legal question that can't just be decided superficially, see for example California's AB5 (but even under that law, a seller is not an employee). As articulated by [SSA](https://www.ssa.gov/section218training/advanced_course_10.htm)

> The common law control test is the basic test, using the common law
> rules, for determining whether a relationship exists between the
> worker and the person or firm that they work for. Under the common-law
> test, the employer has the right to tell the employee what to do, how,
> when, and where to do the job

If the Dept. of Labor or the IRS determine that you are (would be) an employee, then this is illegal discrimination, otherwise it is not. Since you are not paid a wage, the prospects for being deemed an employee are extremely dim. The EEOC gives [this guidance](https://www.eeoc.gov/federal-sector/digest/digest-equal-employment-opportunity-law-13#article) on the distinction, with a very long list of examples which in general support the position that a vendor is an independent contractor and not an employee.

Comment: So you can discriminate against a contractor but not against an employee?

Comment: Yes, that is the distinction. I'm leaving out the possibility that state laws could be stricter, but even then I don't know of a state that applies such laws to contracts.

Comment: A seller on Amazon is neither an employee or a contractor. A seller is someone who sells  products on Amazon's store.

Comment: @DaveD True. I guess a seller is a "customer"? Or perhaps a business partner ?

Comment: @user6726 So at a federal level, I could ask a contractor about his religious beliefs and make my business decision based on his answer ?

Answer (score 2):

A seller on Amazon is neither an employee or a contractor. From Amazon's FAQ for Selling on Amazon:

> **What is selling on Amazon?**
>
> Selling on Amazon is a program that lets individuals and businesses sell their products and inventory on in [sic] Amazon's stores, like Amazon.com.

The form you are completing is to apply to sell products on Amazon's stores.

I can't find the specific reason that Amazon asks for both citizenship and country of birth. However, Amazon is an international company that is required to follow the laws of all countries in which it transacts business. It is possible to purchase products from outside one's own country. Amazon takes on liability to regulate its marketplaces on an international basis and adhering to those regulations may require knowing both country of citizenship as well as country of birth of the seller of a product.

Here is a [question asked](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/t/country-of-birth-not-listed-us-citizen-trying-to-sell-in-us-marketplace/604076/6) by someone who was unable to register as a seller because of their country of citizenship or birth:

[image: Amazon description of lack of support for Russia/Azerbaijan]

In this message from Amazon they indicate that they cannot register someone who was born in or is a citizen of Russia or Azerbaijan.

While I can't identify the specific reason that Amazon asks this question, in order to adhere to the regulations for selling internationally it seems that it could be quite reasonable or even necessary to ask the question.

A seller on Amazon is someone who sells their products via Amazon's marketplace. Employment discrimination laws would have no bearing as the seller is not an employee.

Comment: Wow interesting find. How does Amazon not get sued for that? If someone walks into my shop and I say "sorry I hear you have a Russian accent, I can't do business with people born in Russia, even though you are a US citizen now", how would I not get sued?

Comment: can you please share the link to where you found that response?

Comment: @CodyBugstein Sorry, I should have added the link initially - it is now there.

Comment: @CodyBugstein - there's a significant difference between refusing to sell to someone who enters your shop and refusing to carry the products of another vendor. Using your analogy, Amazon is the shop and you, a potential seller, are a vendor. In order to sell your products through Amazon you have to meet certain requirements. My answer is based on the supposition that there are international regulations that Amazon must meet and the information requested is necessary to meet those regulations. Given Amazon's model it is highly unlikely they're doing it in order to discriminate illegally.

Comment: I am not alleging that Jeff Bezos is racist and is deliberately blocking people born in certain countries out of some personal malice. However I think my analogy is perfect. I (living and operating in the US, regardless of whether or not I also have non-US business) cannot refuse to do business with someone simply because I don't like the country they were born in.

Comment: Based on what Amazon does, assuming it is legal, it would then also be legal for an Iranian-American with a restaurant in the US, to refuse to serve a customer who was born in Israel, just for example. Ditto for an Armenian-American restaurant owner and an Azerbaijani customer

Comment: @CodyBugstein Employment and accommodations have special laws that prohibit discrimination while many other areas just don't. You can quit your job because you don't like having a male boss. You can refuse to go to a local restaurant because the manager is Mexican. It's wrong but not illegal. As far as I know, there are no regulations that prohibit national origin discrimination when a business makes its choice of suppliers. Though I can't for the life of me think of any legitimate reason why Amazon would care what country a vendor was born in.

Comment: If you're allowed to discriminate against who to do business with, then what's this all about? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masterpiece_Cakeshop_v._Colorado_Civil_Rights_Commission

Comment: 2 words: [US Sanctions](https://www.trade.gov/knowledge-product/russia-sanctions)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz US Sanctions?

Comment: @Trish I'm not aware of any US sanctions that are based on a person's country of birth. Can you cite any that would apply to, say, a naturalized US citizen who came here as a child after being born in some other country?

Comment: @CodyBugstein That was about an accommodation, that is, a service provided for a fee. Here, Amazon is choosing *vendors*. So far as I know, there are no laws that prohibit national origin discrimination in a company's choice of vendors. (It wouldn't terribly surprise me if there were any, but I don't know of any. I found one article that claimed NY had such a law, but the cited law said no such thing.)

Comment: I think it's a bit of a leap to believe that Amazon is asking for country of birth in order to discriminate. I can think of a few reasons for asking but don't know for sure why they're asking so I tried not to speculate too much in my answer. I did go down the sanctions path but there are so many and they are so complex that it took no time to get lost in them. While I don't know of any sanctions based on a person's country of birth, it's possible that some countries don't allow citizens born there to renounce their citizenship. Again, sanctions are a morass and that's why I left them out.

Answer (score 1):

If you look under `Help/Policies/Program Policies/Countries accepted for seller registration`, both Russia and Azerbaijan are included, so you can reside there and sell in the US. Iran and North Korea are excluded (presumably due to sanctions).

If I had to guess, both the form asking about citizenship and the helpdesk answer Dave D. found are due to employee incompetence rather than company intent.

Perhaps there are other countries where Amazon sells and where, due to local laws, asking about the country of birth makes sense, and so this feature unintentionally made it into the interface for US sellers.

Comment: Russia is under sanctions by the US for the 2014 Ukraine incidents.

Comment: @Trish Those [are not sanctions on countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_sanctions), but only on some persons from those countries. Further, there are no sanctions on Azerbaijan any of its citizens.

Comment: https://www.trade.gov/knowledge-product/russia-sanctions - its against anyone who works in some fields.

Comment: If a person is born in North Korea and becomes an American citizen, he remains under some form of sanctions?

Comment: @CodyBugstein The sanctions on N. Korea apply to the country itself. What citizenship you have is irrelevant. What matters is that you are **in** N. Korea. You could be a US-born US citizen.

Answer (score -3):

Well realistically, it is your choice to sign up for Amazon. They're not making you give them your country of birth. They're telling you "If you want to use our services, you have to give us your country of birth," rather than "We're forcing you to give us your country of birth either way." It's like Apple taking 40% of developer income through iOS apps. They aren't a monopoly. They aren't the only company that sells smartphones. They say "If you use our service, we're taking 40%." So, no. It would not be legal. And as far as suing them, I'm not sure how far you would get with that. What they're doing is completely legal.